# Inkscape: How to position arrowhead exactly at the end of path?

Tags: inkscape

When I add markers to a path in Inkscape (e.g. arrowheads), they do not exactly end at the end of the path.
How can I position the arrowhead so that it exactly ends at the end of the path?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Os9azgs.png]

Comment: This issue is tracked here: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/1980

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path marker functionality in Inkscape is woefully limited. I would suggest creating your arrowhead as a separate path object, from scratch. It's definitely cumbersome for designs that include a large number of arrows, but you will have a lot more control over the size and position of the arrowhead.

Comment: Can I access the arrowhead "sources" from inkscape? If I were to create a group of a path and a separate arrowhead object, can I restrict the arrowhead from changing when e.g. resizing the group?

Comment: You can obtain an Inkscape arrowhead as a path (to position precisely) by applying the arrowhead to a path and then choosing "Path" > "Stroke to path".

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy way to resize a group without affecting the size of all containing objects. Interesting idea though!

Answer (score 7):

The point at which the marker will “graft” onto the path is the center of the defined marker (i.e. 0,0).

You can position it by changing the path definition either globally in the `markers.svg` (on Windows something like `c:\programs\Inkscape\share\markers\markers.svg`), or by changing the marker definition in the SVG itself with the XML editor.

In the image below, I have changed the tip of the arrow to be at 0,0.

[image: change marker definition in file itself]

However, it is hard to get the position 100% correct since the stroke of the arrow will add some width.

One problem you might encounter (depending on your “main” path definition, size of marker, width of path, etc.) is that the main path might bleed through the marker (see below)

[image: marker does not cover path completly]

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the other options in this thread: you can change the nodes by adding a border. Like so:

[image: border around node does the trick]

The border must be chosen so that it sits at the right distance from the node. Then simply **group** the node and the border together, and make the border invisible. A connector will now sit at exactly the distance you want it to be.

The disadvantage of this is that the backedges are now also at a distance from the node. This may or may not be a problem for you. If it is, then one way of solving this is creating an "extension marker". Create a horizontal line: and choose "object to marker" in the "object" menu.

[image: The fixing start marker]

Then select this new marker as a start marker for your connectors.

Answer (score 2):

I find having "Snap bounding boxes" enabled is the easiest way to make sure that the arrow tip gets aligned to the edge of the other item.

I then resise the stroke with the arrow head such that it aligns with the bounding box of the line. Take a look at this screenshot for the snap settings
[image: inkscape snap settings]

and the screenshot below for this method in action in inkscape.

[image: inkscape screenshot of snap to bounding boxes].

Answer (score 1):

My way:

1) Draw your arrow and an extra line/bar

[image: Step 1]

2) Place the arrow manually (without snapping) as you wish the arrowhead shall be to other objects. Place the bar at the arrowhead (snapping).

[image: Step 2]

3) Make the bar 100% transparent (0% opaque).
[image: Step 3]

Finally: Group the arrow and the bar so you can use copies of this group for well aligned/positioned arrows.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Inkscape (surely at v1.3.2), while setting the **End Marker** from the **Fill and Stroke** panel, a pop-up panel shows up, offering to modify, among other settings, also the **Offset X**.
This makes the tip to end where the line ends.

[image: end marker settings]

This applies *only to the selected line*, as it is not kept as default for the next one, not even if in the same drawing.
So I usually modify the end marker on one line and then copy the line format with `Ctrl+Shift+V`.