# Fix the arrow overflow

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to make an arrow just touch the line it points to?

The question is same as to [this one in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/554621/inkscape-arrow-pokes-shape)

[image]

the type of arrow does not matter, just to make it work

Comment: Let's hope Inkscape 1.2 fixes it. v1.2 is already available as beta and it's said to have substantially improved marker functionality, but I do not have run it. Try it or use some workaround. Here are few of them: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/inkscape-how-to-position-arrowhead-exactly-at-the-end-of-path and here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117793/how-to-prevent-arrowheads-from-overlapping-objects-in-inkscape and you'll surely find more.

Comment: @user287001 - yes 1.2 has some improvements. You can offset the arrow marker in the arrows dropdown. [see example](https://imgur.com/BKd9vLZ) - however I wouldn't recommend using 1.2 just yet,  it's still a bit buggy on Windows at least.  Also, just offsetting the arrow is maybe not the best way to do this, as it will reveal the stroke under the arrow at its tip.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least one easy fix, but it's manual.

Switch off snapping temporarily

Click and drag the node away from the vertical line while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain the movement horizontally.

[image]

In Inkscape 1.1 you can also offset a marker, but you need to go into the XML Editor to do it. In the next version of Inkscape, it should be easier to do this from within the GUI, in the marker dropdown.